# How to export and print the PCB in Altium

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

Hi I have done a very basic PCB (only one layer) with Altium, but when I'm trying to export the pdf, the obtained file has different sizes: in particular my 15x15cm circuit is expanded to the whole A4 page.
How can I export the PCB in a manner such that the defined sizes are respected?
I don't need the gerber file, since I'm going to use press n'peel to print it, I need only a proportionel and well sized pdf or image.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the 'Page Setup' at 'Scaling Mode' select 'Scaled Print' (instead of the default 'Fit Document on Page') and then set the Scale to 1.00

Once you've printed it, double check a couple of measurements in different areas of the board in case your printer doesn't scale perfectly enough.

[image]