# How do I fix this issue where Altium wants to print multiple pages?

Tags: altium

I am trying to print out a PCB scaled 1:1 in order to ensure that my components and mounting holes are lined up perfectly. I've followed these exact instructions to do so: [How to export and print the PCB in Altium](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/159531/how-to-export-and-print-the-pcb-in-altium)

I am able to get the PCB properly scaled. However when I go to print Altium insists on spreading out my board across multiple pages. As you can see in the picture below, it is like Altium wants to justify the verical half way line with the left side of the page 2.

I just would like to have one page printed. If that's not an option, a way to export a 1:1 scale print to another program would suffice. I would appreciate any advice on solving this issue.

[image: Altium Print-Out]

Comment: Check under File->Page Setup that you have 'Center' checked for the horizontal margins.

Comment: I see it. It is checked already.

Comment: Maybe it's too wide. Try printing Portrait.

Comment: I've tried it in Portrait and Landscape.

Comment: Try another printer. If you don't have one, install something like CutePDF and try that. Maybe the driver is fubar.

Comment: I've tried printing it as PDF document and it gives me the same issue. Seems to be my Altium install messing up.